# What does w{%A}(!i+1) mean in EViews?

Tags: eviews

Couldn't find any hint about w{} on eviews documents. Any explanation?

w{}(), can't understand how it works.

BTW, how can I print a single variable to command window not print it to a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces in EViews work the way that statements like `eval()` perform in other programming languages. They tell EViews "strip quotes off of this string and evaluate it as valid EViews code".

`%A` is a "program string", a temporary string variable only used when executing an EViews program. `!i` is a "program scalar", a temporary scalar variable only used when executing an EViews program.

It's hard to answer your question without knowing what type of object `W{%A}` is supposed to be. But if `%A` holds a value like `USA`, for example, `W{%A}` will look for an object in your workfile called `WUSA`. If `!i` holds the value `1`, for example, `W{%A}(!i+1)` is equivalent to `WUSA(2)`. This could, for example, be an attempt to grab a particular element of a vector object.

Answer (score 1):

{} can change a variables value (in programming not series) to string. For example if there is **WTR, WCR, KJ**  and **Y** series in our file, following command would be run.

```
%A = "TR"
!i=2
ls Y c W{%A}(!i+1)
```

Means ***ls Y c WTR(3)*** and also

```
%A = "TR"
%B= "CR"
%F="KJ"
!i=3
!k=-1
 ls Y c W{%A}(!i+1) W{%B}(!k-3)  {%F}
```

Means ***ls Y c WTR(4) WCR(-4) KJ***